# Discord.py Loop data to text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi guys im trying to write a function for my university which logs who's in a discord voice channel. However, im trying to output the data into a text file so my tutors can have a file of who was in the channel during the lab session.

This is what I've currently got:

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    with open('students.txt', "w") as file:
    channel = bot.get_channel(my id here)
    members = channel.members
    for member in members:
    file.write(members.display_name)
    with open("students.txt", "rb") as file:
     await ctx.author.send("Student attendence:", file=discord.File(file,"students.txt"))
```

But unfortualty I get no response. Help suggestions? Cheers :)

PS bot=client

Comment: is the function trying to get who is in the channel the moment you run the code or is it trying to update the file as members join the voice channel?

Comment: What you are looking for is this : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_state_update#discord.on_voice_state_update It gets triggered when someone leaves or join a voice channel, then it's up to you to do the logic behind it

Comment: Just who's currently in voice channel for example: Tutors wants to do a register, they type !test and they receive a text document of who's in the channel at the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine, but the only issue is the indentations are off, also you used `members.display_name` instead of `member.display_name` in the `for member in members` loop:

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    with open('students.txt', "w") as file:
        channel = bot.get_channel(id goes here)
        members = channel.members
        for member in members:
            file.write(member.display_name)
    with open("students.txt", "rb") as file:
        await ctx.author.send("Student attendence:", file=discord.File(file, "students.txt"))
```